# Unable to incorporate Regex expression for parsing backslash(\)

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex expression to parse till `\`.  Can you tell me how to create a regex expression.

The code i had created was

```
/[^\]*/
```

Comment: What is the language? Why not split with ``\``? Without examples, it is also a bit unclear.

Comment: Can you give a few examples of input and desired output, it makes our life a little easier when we can test it agaisnt a few things

Answer (score 1):

I find regex101.com really useful for testing regex.

I think you just need an extra backslash...

```
/[^\\]*/
```

Comment: This will match all substrings not containing ``\``. Note it will also match empty locations before each ``\`` in ``\\\``.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get everything until a slash, just use:

```
/(.*?)\\/
```

- `(.*?)` Capture group, containing the text until slash (not included)
- `.*` Match everything 0 or more times.
- `?` make the quantifier (`*`) lazy, so it matches only until the first slash if there are more than one.

Check this: http://regexr.com/3cnld